# Apache Beam KafkaIO Reader & Writer - Error handling and Retry mechanism

Tags: java, error-handling, apache-flink, apache-beam, apache-beam-kafkaio

I'm working on an Apache Beam Pipeline-based implementation and I consume data from a Kafka stream. After doing some processing I need to publish the processed data into three different Kafka topics. As the runner, I use Apache Flink.

My question is, how do I handle errors in the KafkaIO reader and the writer, especially how do we handle the errors and implement a retry mechanism for KafkaIO Writers?

I would like to get some advice on how to do this and appreciate it if anyone can provide some
resources/code samples.

*(Not sure these things handled by the Flink by default.)*

Reader definition

```
KafkaIO.<String, GenericRecord>read()
   .withBootstrapServers(<server>)
   .withTopics(<my topics>)
   .withConsumerConfigUpdates(<my configs>)
   .withKeyDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
   .withValueDeserializerAndCoder(GenericRecordDeserializer.class, GenericRecordCoder.of());
```

Writer definition

```
KafkaIO.<GenericRecord, GenericRecord>write()
   .withBootstrapServers(<server>)
   .withProducerConfigUpdates(<my configs>)
   .withTopic(<topic-name>)
   .withKeySerializer(GenericRecordSerializer.class)
   .withValueSerializer(GenericRecordSerializer.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of catching errors in `KafkaIO`, you can catch errors in the `Beam` pipeline with `TupleTags`, side outputs and a dead letter queue.

You can also use a library in `Beam` to simplify error handling, called [Asgarde](https://github.com/tosun-si/asgarde), example :

```java
final WithFailures.Result<PCollection<Integer>, Failure> resultComposer = CollectionComposer.of(input)
        .apply("Map", MapElements.into(TypeDescriptors.strings()).via((String word) -> word + "Test"))
        .apply("FlatMap", FlatMapElements
                .into(TypeDescriptors.strings())
                .via((String line) -> Arrays.asList(Arrays.copyOfRange(line.split(" "), 1, 5))))
        .apply("ParDo", MapElementFn.into(TypeDescriptors.integers()).via(word -> 1 / word.length()))
        .getResult();
```

A wrapper `CollectionComposer` catch errors in each steps of the pipeline and returns :

- `PCollection` of correct outputs
- `PCollection` of a `Failure` object

The structure of `Failure` object is :

```java
public class Failure implements Serializable {
    private final String pipelineStep;
    private final Integer inputElement;
    private final Throwable exception;
    ....
```

You can then sink the `PCollection` of `Failure` to a `BigQuery` table, GCS bucket or a topic for retry.

I share with you examples from my `Github` repository :

- [Error handling Beam native](https://github.com/tosun-si/teams-league-java-dlq-native-beam-summit/blob/main/src/main/java/fr/groupbees/domain_ptransform/TeamStatsTransform.java)
- [Error handling Beam Asgarde](https://github.com/tosun-si/teams-league-java-dlq-asgarde-beam-summit/blob/main/src/main/java/fr/groupbees/domain_ptransform/TeamStatsTransform.java)

You can also check this article : [Dead letter queue for errors with Beam, Asgarde, Dataflow and alerting in real time](https://medium.com/google-cloud/dead-letter-queue-for-errors-with-beam-asgarde-dataflow-and-alerting-in-real-time-5745225e12b7)

Comment: You are welcome :)
I hope this solution will help you.

Comment: is it really good with kafka?

Comment: this approach and lib are suitable only for transformations, when you can handle all elements, its not working with any IO in Beam

Comment: Yes, currently the library allows error handling in transformations and not in IOs. There are some discussions on this topic in the Beam team and a reflection on adding dead letter queue in IOs.